# How do I determine which calendar entry is breaking my Android calendar sync?

Tags: sync, google-calendar, samsung-touchwiz

First a bit of background for those who aren't familiar: Just a few weeks ago Samsung released their ICS build of TouchWiz, and my phone (a Samsung Galaxy SII) updated over the air. Ever since none of my calendars have synced. It turns out there's a bug wherein recurring events that were present before the update (I think it's only them?) can cause calendars to stop syncing. (I've searched in vain for a concise link to the problem to reference... )

I've tried factory resetting to no avail and I've tried deleting all my extraneous calendars and the recurring events I could find, but sync still doesn't want to work. Is there any way that I can track down which events are causing the trouble more precisely?

Comment: Where are you syncing them from/to?

Comment: As it turns out it doesn't matter the original source - Facebook, Exchange, and Google accounts all have the same problem. The to: is my phone.

Comment: You could have a look at the log (via [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) or '[adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) logcat') and see what it tells

Comment: I used aLogcat and it made my head spin just a little. I can more-or-less read the individual lines but controlling what the hell it's showing me is a nightmare. I wish I could tell it to just look at one activity stack. I did manage to scrounge out the following message: "not retrying sync operation because error is a hard error" That means it's a database error, I think, but it's not terribly specific. :/

Comment: there are some filtering options, fyi. You could also post a saved logcat output on pastebin or so but *please* mind the privacy impact (logs have personal data sometimes).

Comment: I just nuked my entire Google calendar - cleaned it of ALL events - and it still doesn't want to sync. There's a much deeper error here. I think it's time to call Samsung.

Comment: Hmm, I guess Samsung will just tell you to wipe maybe. Is there another Android phone to cross-check? Maybe post the logcat output to pastebin and link here (maybe strip out private info first before you do so)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's typically frowned upon to answer your own question, but I have. This was a total PEBKAC. I use a different calendar app than the default, so I disabled the pre-installed Samsung calendar in the Application settings in order to stop it appearing in my application list. This is fine and doesn't affect anything, but I apparently got a little trigger happy and also quite stupidly disabled the Calendar Storage process. Yeah, that'll mess up calendar sync something fierce.

Comment: Answering one's own question is OK here. You can accept it in 2 days and will earn a [badge](http://android.stackexchange.com/badges/13/self-learner) if you get 3+ votes on it. Thanks for letting us know the real reason, by the way!

Comment: No worries - hopefully it helps someone else avoid the same mistake!